# Can source command be successfully run through python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have done multiple ways to get source command to run but python does not store those env variables.

```
        command = shlex.split("env -i bash -c './var/easy-rsa/vars'")
        subprocess.Popen('command', shell=True)
```

Also tried

```
        os.system(". /var/easy-rsa/vars")
```

also tried calling source from a shell script. Do you know of a way around this problem?

Comment: You're sourcing those files in processes separate to the running python oricess

Answer (score 0):

Split.os.popen(“env ...)

https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/
Popen executes the command in a new process, try process.stdout.readline()